# Hibernate error when using HQL Editor to query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi guys I'm trying to retrieve data from my database using the HQL Editor to query. I followed the steps in the example "Using Hibernate in a Java Swing Application". My config files is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobilecarriers?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">######</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property>
    <mapping resource="mobilecarriers/entity/National.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 23 Sep 2012 11:26:47 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mobilecarriers.entity.National" table="national" catalog="mobilecarriers">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="dominantSecondLanguage" type="string">
            <column name="DominantSecondLanguage" length="25" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Using this: `from national` or `from National` i get the following errors:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:912)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from limit 100'
>   at line 1     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)     ... 8 more

Comment: your query statement has an error as per the logs , post/check  your query please

Comment: You forgot about the mapping. Please update your question.

Comment: I'm querying from the HQL Editor and tried both "from National" and "from national"

Comment: @Satya   
I'm querying from the HQL Editor and tried both "from National" and "from national".

Comment: @bussambule, Hibernat should print the query that is sent to MySQL. Please try to find that in your logs. And I would also remove the c3po settings for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from mobilecarriers.entity.National
```